# Unable to insert a data in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> DESC USER;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| u_id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| MOBILE_NUMBER | int(12)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password      | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO USER (MOBILE_NUMBER,password) VALUES('9619362665','Ashish1');
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'MOBILE_NUMBER' at row 1
```

Comment: Use `VARCHAR(..) CHARACTER SET ascii` for phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That number `9619362665 (9,619,362,665)` is too big

[Click This Link to See the Max Integer Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/integer-types.html).

The biggest `INT` is `2147483647 (2,147,483,647)`.

If you want to store numbers larger than `2147483647`, change the column as follows

```
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY COLUMN MOBILE_NUMBER BIGINT;
```

Then, the `INSERT` should work.